# Problems with images in react application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, frontend

When using images in react, there is either a problem with typescript, or the image breaks on the site.

To solve the problem, I tried:

1. Add url-loader and file-loader to the webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const BUILD_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './build');
const SRC_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/');
const PUBLIC_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './public')

module.exports = {
  entry: SRC_PATH + '/index.tsx',

  output: {
    path: BUILD_PATH,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',

  resolve: {
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },

  devServer: {
    static: PUBLIC_PATH,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.module.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 8192,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
    }),
  ],
};
```

2. Import images as components

```
import React from 'react';

import logo from './header-logo.svg';

import styles from './Header.module.scss';

export const Header = () => {
  return <header className={styles.header}>
    <img src={logo} />
  </header>
};
```

3. Create the images.d.ts file in the src/types directory

```
declare module "*.svg" {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

4. And I even tried svgr..

But nothing helped. If I delete the images.d.ts file, typescript cannot detect the module when importing. When using images.d.ts, vscode does not show errors, but the picture is not displayed in the browser, and instead of the normal path, something strange data:image/svg+xml;base64,ZXhwb3J0IGRlZmF1bHQgX193ZWJwYWNrX3B1YmxpY19wYXRoX18gKyAiZWMzYzM1Nzg3YTljZTMyMzE4M2NmMzM2Y2EzMDBkOTkuc3ZnIjs=

And just in case, I attach tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

I'm new to react so please don't judge strictly for stupid mistakes. I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: You are making things harder by not using a ready solution like `create-react-app`

Comment: I wanted to try configure webpack, because I suppose it will be necessary for other stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, I came to the conclusion that perhaps the problem occurred due to a loaders conflict. Leaving only the **file-loader** and deleting the **url-loader**, I was able to solve the problem. I hope my solution can help someone in the future.

My files now look like this:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const SRC_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './src');
const BUILD_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './build');
const PUBLIC_PATH = path.resolve(__dirname, './public')

module.exports = {
  entry: SRC_PATH + '/index.tsx',

  output: {
    path: BUILD_PATH,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',

  resolve: {
    modules: [SRC_PATH, 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },

  devServer: {
    static: PUBLIC_PATH,
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.module.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|svg)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: PUBLIC_PATH + '/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

A **imges.d.ts** file for type resolution for typescript

```
declare module "*.jpg";
declare module "*.png";
declare module "*.svg";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [svg-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-url-loader) npm module. in webpack.config,js

```
{
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "svg-url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

in your component

```
// pass a correct path
import logo from './header-logo.svg';

 <img src={logo} alt="" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Unfortunately, this didn't help me solve the problem